# Por que no me deja acomodar de manera correcta mi input y span?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con la forma de acomodar mi `form-group` con `bootstrap 3`.
Espero que me puedan ayudar a acomodarlo, por favor.
Se ve de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
            <div class="form-group row">

              <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-right:0px">

                <div class="input-group">

                  <span class="input-group-addon"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                  <i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></button>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="agregar" name="agregar" placeholder="Nombre del producto" required>

                </div>


              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-3">

                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevaCantidad" name="nuevaCantidad" placeholder="0"
                min="1" required>

              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:0px">

                <div class="input-group">

                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevaCantidad" name="nuevaCantidad" placeholder="000000" min="1" readonly required>

                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ion ion-social-usd"></i></span>

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Saludos @PedroMontiel, bienvenido a stackoverflow, podrías por favor colocar que has intentado para intentar solucionar este problema que tienes?

Comment: Hola @DavidVillegas, pues lo que he intentado a sido agregar `<div class="input-group">
 <span class="input-group-addon"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
   <i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></button>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="agregar" name="agregar" style="float: none;" placeholder="Nombre del producto" required>
</div>`. Y he puesto `input-group-addon` en todas las clases, pero creo es mas un error eso, que una solucion.

Comment: @DavidVillegas ya encontre mi error, era debido a que `</button>` lo estaba poniendo fuera del `</span>`, cuando era antes de `</span>`